# Ember.js find with plain object is not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I use Ember.js to get items like this:

```
App.MyData.find()
```

And to get item like this:

```
App.MyData.find(itemId)
```

And then I use filter and return it in model function like this:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({   
    model: function()   {
        return App.MyData.find().filter(function(a)
        {
            return a.get('desc') != null;
        });
    } 
});
```

And it's working just fine.

Now I wanted to pass another parameter to underlying PHP script returning items. So I used "Querying For Records [desc](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/finding-records/)":

"If you provide a plain object as the second argument to find, Ember Data will make a GET request with the object serialized as query params. This method returns DS.PromiseArray **in the same way as find with no second argument**."

According to the documentation it should behave the same way like find with no plain object argument.

But it does not. My view is not displaying anymore.

I checked GET request. It returns exactly the same data.

I have no errors in JS.

What to do to pass parameter to PHP while getting items in a way it will work?

Comment: Could you please post the URL generated by your `find` function. And the find function with the query?

Comment: You are also using a really old version of ember-data, I'm not sure queries were supported back then.

Comment: @albertjan you mean the GET query? it's like .../mydata?param=value so it is ok and the response from PHP is also good.

Comment: @runspired my version has a find function so i think it's kinda supported... or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/batitipozi/4/edit?html,js,output) it does work. So if it doesn't work for you you either have a really old version or you're doing something else wrong.

I use this to get the model:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('thing', { beer: 'heineken' });
  }
});
```

and that results in this request: `GET /things?beer=heineken".`